# Changing View without changing Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am unsure how to phrase my question, exactly, so my apologies if it's not clear.

I'm using a library I found on Cocoa Controls, specifically this one:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/lmdropdownview

In their demo they simply change the Map Type based on the selection of the menu items. Could this be used to load a new view instead? And would it be possible to do so without affecting the current Navigation Bar?

My best guess would be a page view that slides to the left / right by 640px depending on the menu item selected. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Just had a look at the control you gave.

> Could this be used to load a new view instead?

Yes, you simply need to override the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method of the `LMViewController` class from the demo project:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(self.dropdownView.animationDuration * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //self.currentMapTypeIndex = indexPath.row; //remove this line
        // create and navigate to another view controller
});
```

> And would it be possible to do so without affecting the current Navigation Bar?

No, if you have to navigate to another view controller. Unfortunately, you need to construct another vertical menu items. But if you're talking about the `UIPageViewController` there won't be navigation at all, just load another page.